# Discriminatable key-value tuple type (of a given object)

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
interface Obj {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
type ObjKey = keyof Obj;
type ObjVal<Key extends ObjKey> = Obj[Key];
type ObjTuple<Key extends ObjKey> = [Key, ObjVal<Key>];
```

I want to create a function that takes in a tuple (of unknown type), and discriminates the `Key` part (at index 0), to figure out what the value type is:

```js
function doThings(tuple: ObjTuple): string {
  switch (tuple[0]) {
    case "bar":
      return tuple[1].toFixed();
    case "foo":
      return tuple[1];
  }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work, as the type argument for `ObjTuple` is missing. Since I don't want to specify it (the function should figure out what type it is), I changed the declaration to have `ObjKey` as default:

```js
type ObjTuple<Key extends ObjKey = ObjKey> = [Key, ObjVal<Key>];
```

Sadly, the discrimination is not working at all. TypeScript correctly detects the allowed variants of the key (e.g. tells me when a code path is missing, or when the switch contains an impossible key), but the value is always a union of all the variants.

[Here is a link to a playground, with the final code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kBnMKUAcwG4Dl04oKQBXAW3WiYC+eMAE8ADigyYA0hBHIAvMgDWc4jDRYmoiZswA1OABsAPLPkQAHpBAATSnvMA+RXoDa5gLrbxkrABVOMSMIMzlkKxt7R3ClKWdXDzkAGj1DU2dvPDwYThAEMGBiEGRbYn8AC3pKAAowIJCKKUDgiABKCmpaEDpcZkoAd2AwBArkOoaINwAGTza+wkIEOEoUACJWKDWyZkXkKAh6qBL61rcARk8AOjBiADFgSwhbGramPeXV5DWSYm3dxYHI4nSYXLKEIQCIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the type of `ObjVal`. The editor is not doing us a favor when displaying it but here is how the expanded type looks like:

```
type ObjTuple = ["foo" | "bar", string | number]
```

That does not look right at all since there is not correlation between specific properties and types anymore. Both elements are just a union.

We rather want a type which looks like this:

```
type ObjTuple = ["foo", string] | ["bar", number]
```

And we can generate this one using `ObjTuple` with one modification. We need to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over `Key`.

```
type ObjTuple<Key extends ObjKey = ObjKey> = Key extends Key 
  ? [Key, ObjVal<Key>]
  : never
```

This should solve the issue.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kBnMKUAcwG4Dl04oKQBXAW3WiYC%20eMAE8ADigyYA0hBHIAvMgDWc4jDRYmoiZswA1OABsAPLPkQAHpBAATSnvMA%20RXoDa5gLpNh4yVgAVTjEjCDM5ZCsbe0cIpSlnV3NI6wg7B2TmAH5kDzkAGj1DU2dPZg4IADdoPDwYThAEMGBiEGRbYgCAC3pKAAowYNCKKSCQiABKCmpaEDpcZkoAd2AwBC7kAaGINwAGTwmFwkIEOEoUACJWKAuyZmPkKAhBqDbB8bcARk8AOjBiABiwEsEFsfQmTAep3OyAuJGIt3uxyeLze2y%203mYQgEQA)

Comment: Perfect! But sadly not very intuitive... I guess some reading is required, thanks.